# VBA Issue with Number formatted as text when numbers include comma

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting, xls

I use a vba script to open another workbook. This workbook is in format .XLS and the content from a DB was stored like:

```
"Name1"  "0"  "7,98"   
"Name2"  "5"  "1"  
"Name3"  "2"  "7,1"
```

When opening the workbook with a VBA script, every cell that includes a comma, is interpreted as text and shows this warning:
[image: The number in this cell is formatted as text or is preceded by an apostrophe]
The number in this cell is formatted as text or is preceded by an apostrophe

Strangely, if I open the file by double clicking, the numbers are just formatted as text and don't show any error. I guess, Excel is doing some interpretting, which doesn't work.
My code is:

```
Dim WorkBookImport As Workbook
Name = Application.GetOpenFilename()
If Name <> False Then
   Set WorkBookImport = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Name)
End If
```

I tried everything from:

```
Range(mycolumn).Value = Range(mycolumn).Value
```

For loop with CDbl(.Value)
Range(mycolumn).TextToColumns  ...

Nothing works ;( Please help!

Comment: Are you certain of how that is stored in your xls workbook?  With the double quotes appearing in all the cells?  If I create an xls, with quotes surrounding the contents of each cell, when I OPEN the file, whether with double-clicking on the file, or using the Workbook.Open method, the double quotes are retained.  Is each line that you show in three separate cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Sub edksg()
    Dim c As Range
    
    Set c = Sheet1.Range("D3")
    
    c.Value2 = CDbl(c.Value2)
    
End Sub
```

Works fine for me when cell D3 of the worksheet is formatted as text.

Of course, my location uses the comma as decimal separator, so if your location uses a different standard, the issue might be there. In that case, doing something like `CDbl(Replace(c.Value2, ",", Application.DecimalSeparator, 1, -1, vbBinaryCompare))` might solve that part of the issue.

If you want to loop through the entirety of some column, the end result might look something like this, assuming the values you want to convert to numbers are in column C.

```
Option Explicit

Sub edksg()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim r As Range
    
    Set r = Sheet1.Range("C1:C" & Sheet1.Range("C" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    
    For Each c In r
        If Len(c) > 0 Then
            c.Value2 = CDbl(Replace(c.Value2, ",", Application.DecimalSeparator, 1, -1, vbBinaryCompare))
        End If
    Next c
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @eirikdaude. It so strange, when I replace Replace(c.Value2, ",", ",", 1, -1, vbBinaryCompare)) that works and all errors are gone. I have no idea why the comma was somehow not recognized.

Answer (score 1):

It´s a problem with the formating of the cells. You should use NumberFormat to change it.

```
Sub FormatNumber()
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YourWorkbook").Range("YourRange") = CDbl(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YourWorkbook").Range("YourRange"))
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YourWorkbook").Range("YourRange").NumberFormat = "General"
End Sub
```

With NumberFormat you can also change it to text if you have the opposite problem, in this case you would use `NumberFormat = "@"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm getting a Type mismatch for the CDbl line, because the "9,78" is stored as text, I guess.

Comment: The CDbl-Function only throws an error if you give it a text, if its a number formated as text, there are no problems. Maybe you selected a range which not only contents numbers.